# Completed with errors, not showing in source tree

Tags: git, clone, git-submodules, atlassian-sourcetree, git-clone

I have cloned a project using source tree which came out with the following error:

> No submodule mapping found in .gitmodules for path
>   'frontend/bower_components/global' Completed with errors, see
>   above.

I have been told to just ignore the error for now, but the project is not showing in SourceTree, I can see the files in win explorer but the projects is not showing up in source tree. How can I get the project in sourcetree?

Answer (score 0):

I think the mapping of the .gitmodules for the path 'frontend/bower_components/global' are not found.

```
$ git rm --cached frontend/bower_components/global
```

and then update the submodule again. It should work fine.

http://en.saturngod.net/no-submodule-mapping-found-in-gitmodules

Or

Add the submodule by using the following command

```
$ git submodule add [URL] [PATH_TO_SUBMODULE]
```

I hope this will help you show the files in source tree.